# Change of tense from present to imperfect

Tags: poetry, tenses

In the Metamorphoses there is a line as follows:

*Nil prosunt artes erat inmedicabile vulnus*

Why would the first sentence be in the present tense, but the second one be in the imperfect? I would have expected *est* instead of *erat*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's actually quite common to switch from the historic present to other past tenses. Here are some examples from Pinkster's *Oxford Latin Syntax*, vol. I, 7.16, with the historic present in **bold** and narrative past tenses in *italic*:

> Interea ea legione, quam secum *habebat*, militibus que, qui ex provincia *convenerant* . . . fossam . . . **perducit**. (Caesar, *De Bello Gallico*, 1.8)

(Note the use of the pluperfect to indicate a completed action in the past, despite the narrative present in the main clause.)

> Sermonem ibi nobiscum **copulat**. **ait** sé peregrinum esse huius ignarum oppidi; . . . nos hominem ad te *adduximus*. (Plautus, *Poenulus*, 655-58)

(This example is especially relevant because, after a long narration in the present tense, the "switch" to the end of the story is signaled by the perfect tense.)

> sic **ait** et dextra crinem **secat**, omnis et una
> dilapsus calor atque in uentos uita *recessit*. (Vergil, *Aeneid*, 4.704-705)

(Again relevant because of the shift to the perfect tense at the end.)

My own observation about your passage from Ovid is that it employs the present tense to create a vivid impression of immediacy. Present and past tenses are used throughout the narration, but this particular sequence contains a high concentration of present tenses, and the final imperfect (at least to my ear) allows us to "zoom out" and again see the event as happening in the past:

> *expalluit* aeque
> quam puer ipse deus conlapsosque **excipit** artus,
> et modo te **refovet**, modo tristia vulnera **siccat**,
> nunc animam admotis fugientem **sustinet** herbis.
> nil **prosunt** artes: *erat* inmedicabile vulnus.  (Ovid, *Metamorphoses* 10.185-89)

English might employ a similar device: "He tries the door. He knocks on the door. He cries for help. All was lost."

As you can see, there's a pretty free change from past tenses to the historic present, and Pinkster's discussion offers many more such examples. Pinkster (pg. 404) notes:

> Ex. (a) [i.e. the Plautus example above] shows that, in order for a hearer/reader to be able to interpret a present tense as 'historic', there must be a sufficient number of 'past signals' in the context or in the communicative situation. **Narratives rarely start or end with (a) historic present(s)**. (emphasis mine)

He goes on (of course) to note exceptions.

Comment: In Caesar de B. G. 1.8, the use of pluperfect, "convenerant", to indicate a completed action in the past; why not use the perfect tense for this? On this theme, Plautus, Poenulus, 655-58, the use of perfect, "adduximus", to establish the end of the story--everything completed, in the past. What is the difference between these two sets of 'completed action/s'?

Comment: @tony Caesar is using the pluperfect (*convenerant*="had assembled") for a completed action in the **past** (i.e. before the narration) and the perfect (*adduximus*="have brought") for a completed action in the **present** (i.e. part of the narration). The point is that the "historical present" functions as if it were a past tense with respect to which completed actions can still be in the pluperfect.